# Opening an URL in a pop-up window in rShiny

Tags: popup, rshiny

I'm trying to open a pop-up window to open with an URL using URLmodal() method as per the link
https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/man/urlModal.html

Can someone pls show a way to open google.com in a pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

The `urlModal()` will only show the url text in a modal dialog (using `showModal()`), as described in the docs.

If you need to open a new window of the browser as a popup, you can do it with some javascript inserted as an HTML tag in the UI part of your app:

```
HTML('<button id="go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.google.com\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');">Go</button>')
```

See [this](https://www.quackit.com/javascript/popup_windows.cfm) as reference to change options.